# Slow xmlsec package build with pip install

Tags: python, pip, xmlsec

I'm using `xmlsec 1.3.3` in my python web application.
Every time I run a clean `pip install`, this is the package it hangs on, for about 5 minutes. 
The package size is 15KB and pip show a `using cached...` message, so I guess the time is taken by building some specific security libraries.

Is there a way to do a clean pip install, but without rebuilding the xmlsec related libraries?

Comment: I believe pip should build a `wheel` of `xmlsec` on the first installation and then use this for the following installations.

Answer (score 1):

`xmlsec` is distributed in [source code only](https://pypi.org/project/xmlsec/1.3.3/#files) but it's [written in C](https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/tree/master/src) so `pip` needs to compile it on every fresh installation. It's not possible to not compile it.

You can pre-compile it yourself if you use one specific platform and always install from your package instead of PyPI.